# Rule or Formula to get from j^2 + 3j + 2 to (j + 1)(j + 2)

Tags: induction

Apologies in advance if this problem is a duplicate. I'm not even sure how to properly research it.

Studying [algorithms](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithms) (actually still in the prerequisite step of [data structures](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Structures)) and an explanation of the [Principal of Induction](http://en.wikibooks.org/w/index.php?title=Data_Structures/Introduction) demonstrates why:

[image: starting equation]

I was able to deduct that `(j)(j + 1) + 2(j + 1)` = `j^2 + j + 2j + 2`, because you can separately multiply the elements in the parentheses, so `(j)(j + 1)` can be simplified to `j x j` or `j^2` plus `j x 1` or `j`, and similarly with `2(j + 1)`.

But going from

[image: middle equation]

to

[image: end equation]

I can't quite figure out why (j + 1)(j + 2) = j^2 + 3j + 2.

I can fill in j with a number and see that the value is the same, but why?

Wait - I think I'm figuring it out. At least if I do it backwards. Same principal.

Take the `j` in the first paragraph and multiply it by the one in the second: `j^2`, then multiply it by the 2, so we've got `2j`, which leaves us with `1 x J` or `j` and `1 x 2` or `2`. So that's a total of `3j`, `j^2` and `2`.

Going *forwards* from the first equation to the second one, we can take `j^2` and make it `(j)(j)`, but how do `3j` and `2` get incorporated into it?

Wait wait - to get the `3j` we can add `2` to the second `(j)` (making `(j + 2)`), so that the first `(j)` is multiplied by `2` to give us `2j`. Then we add a `1` to the first `(j)` (making `(j + 1)`), which is multiplied by each item in `(j + 2)` resulting in `1j` or `(j)`; the 3rd `j` in `3j`, and the `+ 2` is the result of the `1 x 2`.

Is there a simple rule or formula, or combination of them to get from `j^2 + 3j + 2` to `(j + 1)(j + 2)`?

Comment: I am having some trouble following your question, but I think what you are asking is:  *How do I factor a quadratic polynomial?*  There are a number of basic tutorials on this online, e.g. http://www.purplemath.com/modules/factquad.htm.

Comment: Yes. I think I need to add the following three words to my vocabulary (once I figure out what they mean) factor, quadratic and polynomial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have deduced that $$j(j+1)+2(j+1)=j^2+j+2j+2$$Now you can change the order of the middle terms and reverse the procedure to get $$=j^2+2j+j+2=j(j+2)+(j+2)=(j+1)(j+2)$$

That depends on noticing something special about your particular case. A similar thing can be done in many other cases, but that depends on knowing what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes. I think I need to research the phrase "middle term" and the words factor, quadratic and polynomial.

Comment: @MikeiLL "Middle term" is rather informal. To factor the quadratic $x^2+(a+b)x+ab$ you can rewrite as $x^2+ax+bx+ab=x(x+a)+b(x+a)=(x+b)(x+a)$ or exchange the role of $a$ and $b$. Notice how the coefficient $x$ is the sum $a+b$ and the constant term is the product $ab$.

Comment: I don't even remember what coefficient means, man. Maybe I looked at that word in the 1980's in high school. Need to spend a little more intimate time with PurpleMath to refresh on all this. Didn't realize website development would end up involving so much math. This is algebra, right?